# Error in reading a file from a remote server in SOAPUI 4.5.1 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, soapui

I setup sOAPUI 4.5.1 on Windows XP. It read data file (Excel Format) from a remote server in Data Source correctly.
Now I change Windows to 7 and setup sOAPUI 4.5.1. But I have problem in reading file from remote server and exist Error az below:
"

```
http:\shpnt07\Support\Modernbank%20Maintenance\Shared%20Documents\محصولات%20مدرن\General\Test\Test%20Design\Functional%20Test\Test%20Data\R292\Loan\GetGuarantyList.xls (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

"
While the URL work correctly in Browser.
I try this with Disable and Enable Proxy in browser and SOAPUI.
also I try this with off Firewall and Antivirus.

When Run SoapUI the Error occur on soapui-error.log file:

```
2014-03-18 10:26:27,844 ERROR [errorlog] Network Error for Version Update or Proxy
2014-03-18 10:26:27,846 ERROR [errorlog] java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIVersionUpdate.getLatestVersionAvailable(SoapUIVersionUpdate.java:97)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIVersionUpdate.checkForNewVersion(SoapUIVersionUpdate.java:267)
    at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUIPro$SoapUIProRunner.run(SourceFile:1805)
    at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUIPro.main(SourceFile:288)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

please Help me. This is important and I wait.

Answer (score 0):

The error trace says it is having problem reaching out to soapUI server to look for the latest version of the soapUI. This could be of a proxy between you and the server.

You have two options to resolve this

1. Add proxy details
2. disable check for new version of soapUI. check the image below and leave the option unchecked.

[image]

For the excel file error can you change the `محصولات%20مدرن` folder name to an english name. Maybe it is not able to recognize the special characters. Also, when you give the url in soapUI are you removing %20 part?

Comment: 1. add proxy detail  2.Uncheck. I change the address to English but it doesn't work. this address work with version 4.5.1 in windows XP

Comment: This is interesting..Did you at least stop getting the `Network Error for Version Update or Proxy` error in the soapUI log? Can you try and read excel file using groovy (let me know if you need code for that)? Also, when you give the url in soapUI are you removing %20 part?

Comment: yes the error is stopped. No I can't because I have 100 test suite that used 'DataSource' with this method. yes I change the url address. I think SOApUI would not detect 'http://' address.

Comment: good at least one problem has been solved. I understand that you have to use the datasource step, I just want you to try with groovy because i want to try and isolate the problem with reading the remote file. It will not be the final solution. Unfortunately i do not have access to a pro version of soapUI to actually try this at my end.